# Two different functions with one button

Tags: html, button, leaflet, bootstrap-modal

I need some help assigning two very different functions to a single button. The following code shows an "export" button which exports a .kml file from a leaflet.Draw map, and the "submit" button opens a modal which is used to display a contact form:

**index.html**

```
<a href='#' id='export'>Export Feature</a>    

<button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'">Submit</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="id01" class="modal">
<span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" 
class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
   <div class="form-style" id="contact_form">
....
```

**Script**

```
document.getElementById('export').onclick = function(e) {
        // Extract GeoJson from featureGroup
        var data = featureGroup.toGeoJSON();
        var kml = tokml(data);
        // Convert to dataURL format
        var convertedData = 'application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(kml);

        // Create export
        document.getElementById('export').setAttribute('href', 'data:' + convertedData);
        document.getElementById('export').setAttribute('download','data.kml');
    } 

....

var modal = document.getElementById('id01');
```

What I would like to do is have the modal open up when the feature is exported, using the "export" button.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should add id to your submit button, for example let it be id=submitbtn.
Then in your export onclick you should call document.getElementById('submitbtn').click()

Comment: Thanks for your input. I used your feedback and it helped me find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following to solve my question:

```
<a href='#' id='export'>
    <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'">
        Export Feature
    </span>
</a>
```

I was originally a little confused as the export button is an  and I didn't know how to work this in with a